# How to pass javascript array to and YII action through ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, yii

I'm having a javascript array like

```
var orderItems={'1':{id:'1',name:'Shirt',qty:'0'},'3':{id:'3',name:'Shoe',qty:'0'}, };
```

I need to pass this array to an action using a ajax button.

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
    'label' => 'Click me',
    'type' => 'primary',
    'htmlOptions' => array(
        'data-toggle' => 'modal',
        'data-target' => '#myModal',
        'ajax' => array(
            'type' => 'POST',
            'url' => $this->createUrl('order/AjaxUpdateOrder', 
                                      array('val' => 'profile')),
            'success' => 'function(data) { alert(data) }',
        ),
    ),
));
```

Comment: Please show your code in OrderController's class function actionAjaxUpdateOrder

Comment: Im just trying to access the values within it. nothing more than that

Comment: Do U got Alert (data)? It is executes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prefix 'js:'  to 'data' attribute .. like below

```
    'ajax' => array(
            'type' => 'POST',
            'url' => $this->createUrl('order/AjaxUpdateOrder', 
                                       array('val' => 'profile')),
            'success' => 'function(data) { alert(data) }',
            'data' => 'js:orderItems',
            'processData' => false,
    ),
```